# Tables in Word - Using page breaks within table

Tags: microsoft-word

I am working in a table in MS Word (subscription version online).

How do I use a page break within a Word Table and maintain it being a single (1) table?

When using page break in the table at row I need the break, it splits the table into TWO tables which means I must work with both tables separately to set formatting et al.

This is a REAL PAIN. It is still one table yet covers more than one page in the doc.

HELP PLEASE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When manually inserting a page-break into a table, you are in reality
splitting the table into two separate tables. The new table does not inherit
from the original table attributes such as repeating header rows.

To avoid this problem:

- Put the insertion point at the beginning of the row that you want on the new page
- Choose Paragraph from the ribbon (Home pane, Paragraph group, small icon at
  bottom right)
- In the Paragraph dialog box, position to the tab of "Line and Page Breaks"
- Check "Page break before"
- Click OK.

Now the row will start at the beginning of a new page,
but the table is not "broken" into two parts, so the header will repeat
at the top of each page and all formatting is conserved.

Comment: THANK YOU for quick reply. Just prior to getting your EXCELLENT answer, I found the "break before" option totally buried and with no explanations (by Word). Your help is GREATLY appreciated.